# Accessing height of a div in Nuxt application throws error message

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to access the height of a div in a grid in a Nuxt application.

```html
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3">
    <client-only>
      <Item
        v-for="(
        item, itemIndex
        ) in ItemsArray"
        :key="`item-${itemIndex}`"
        v-bind="item"
        :ref="`item${itemIndex}`"
      />
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.itemHeight = this.$refs.item1.clientHeight
  },
  data() {
    return {
      itemHeight: 0,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But I get this error message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientHeight')`. I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: Fixing some CSS issue with JS is usually not the best way to go. Try to use the tech made for the problem you're actually trying to solve. If you need a `div`, ReactNative is maybe not appropriate, same applies here: why reaching for JS when you only need to find how to achieve it with CSS?

Comment: Also, your components are probably not populated at the `mounted()` exact time, some `nextTick()` may probably help here. But still, prefer finding a CSS solution here.

Comment: @kissu You are probably right but in my case I have got the feeling that my problem was too complex to solve with CSS alone and I needed to reach to Javascript (I have three `div`s in a row, I need to figure out the height of the tallest from the first two `div`s to set the height of the third `div`. The nextTick() has solved it, merci beaucoup Monsieur kissu !!

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you add `ref` in a `v-for` Vue will be creating an array of `refs` and not each `ref` itself.

I'm not currently on my PC but from what I remember you will have to do something like:

```js
mounted() {
  this.itemHeight = this.$refs.item1[0].clientHeight
},
```

If that's not the answer, try to debug with `console.log(this.$refs.item1)` to see exactly how it is structured. From there you will be able to figure out yourself

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have tried `item1[0]` and I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` and  `console.log(this.$refs.item1)` gives me `undefined`. I am wondering if it has something to do with `ssr`.

Comment: @Maxime Try to wrap your code around a `if (process.client) { ... }` to only run that code in a `client`. I'm not very proficient with `nuxt` so you might have to make one or another tweek

Comment: I have tried but no luck... Same result.